# Buliding query with 'For XML Path'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which contains the following data:

Columns: 
Level, Class, Property, Value

Data:

0, Clothes, Shoe1, Nike

0, Clothes, Shoe2, Adidas

0, Clothes, Shoe3, FILA

0, Clothes, Hat, Tom

1, Sweatshirt, Dash1, Red

1, Sweatshirt, Dash2, Blue

I want to produce an xml which contains the data on each level (iterates the level).
This is what I'm expecting:

```
<Root>
 <Level>
   <Clothes>
      <Shoe1>Nike</Shoe1>    
      <Shoe2>Adidas</Shoe2>
      <Shoe3>FILA</Shoe3>
   </Clothes>
   <Clothes>
      <Hat>Tom</Hat>
   </Clothes>
 </Level>
 <Level>
     <Sweatshirt>
         <Dash1>Red</Dash1>             
         <Dash2>Blue</Dash2>
     </Sweatshirt>
 </Level>
</Root>
```

Comment: which RDBMS do you using? is it SQL Server, MySQL or what?

Comment: So do you still need some answers for this or this question should be closed?

Answer (score 0):

try using dbms_xmlgen

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('your query') from dual;
```

you can use cursor for iterating through every item

Comment: I've written:
SELECT @DataOut = Convert(varchar(max), (SELECT [Value] AS Property FROM MyTable WHERE [Level] = 1 FOR XML path ('Level')))

My problem is how to iterate the levels and how to make the element written as property value and not like "<Property>""</Property>"

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try to do something like this

```
select
    cast(
        '<' + T.Class + '>' +
        cast(
            (
                select
                    cast('<' + TT.Property + '>' + TT.Value + '</' + TT.Property + '>' as xml)
                from #MyTable as TT
                where TT.Level = T.Level and TT.Class = T.Class
                for xml path('')
            )
         as nvarchar(max)) +
         '</' + T.Class + '>'
     as xml) as [Level]
from (select distinct TT.Level, TT.Class from #MyTable as TT) as T
for xml path(''), root('Root'), type
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac0eb/2)</kbd>**

It's not that I really like this type of solution. You can also try dynamic SQL

Comment: I'm getting an error : 'Msg 9438, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XML parsing: line 1, character 11, text/xmldecl not at the beginning of input'

Comment: which version of SQL Server do you using?